# Cannot run powershell scripts using a batch file or Task Scheduler invoke web request

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

when we run the script on its own, it works fully by itself, but when we try to use the task scheduler, we get invalid username or password every time.

This is the script:

```
`$apiUri = "https://na2.docusign.net/restapi"
# Download a document from an envelope
# This script uses the envelope_id stored in ../envelope_id.
# The envelope_id file is created by example eg002SigningViaEmail.ps1 or
# can be manually created.
 
 
# Obtain your Oauth access token
$accessToken = Get-Content .\ds_access_token.txt
 
# Obtain your accountId from demo.docusign.net -- the account id is shown in
# the drop down on the upper right corner of the screen by your picture or
# the default picture.
$accountId = Get-Content .\API_ACCOUNT_ID
 
#Variables <3
 
 
# Check that we have an envelope id
 
$headers = @{
    'Authorization' = "Bearer $accessToken";
    'Content-Type'  = "application/json";
  }
 
 
$outputFileExtension = ".pdf"
 
$fromDate = ((Get-Date).AddHours((-21)).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssK"))
try{
$(Invoke-RestMethod `
    -Uri "${apiUri}/v2.1/accounts/${accountId}/envelopes" `
    -Method 'GET' `
    -Headers @{
    'Authorization' = "Bearer $accessToken";
    'Content-Type'  = "application/json";
  } `
    -Body @{ "from_date" = ${fromDate}; "Status" = "Completed" }).envelopes |Select-Object -property envelopeId -ExpandProperty envelopeId| out-file -filepath .\envelopes.txt 
 
}
catch{
Write-Host "error with token"
 
 
}
foreach($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines(".\envelopes.txt"))
{
 
$envelopeId = $line
#documentID
Invoke-RestMethod `
  -Uri "${apiUri}/v2.1/accounts/${accountId}/envelopes/${envelopeId}/documents" `
  -Method 'GET' `
  -Headers $headers |Select-Object -Property EnvelopeDocuments -ExpandProperty EnvelopeDocuments|Select-Object -expandproperty documentId -skipLast 1 |Out-File .\docID.txt 
# ***DS.snippet.0.end
#DocumentName
Invoke-RestMethod `
  -Uri "${apiUri}/v2.1/accounts/${accountId}/envelopes/${envelopeId}/documents" `
  -Method 'GET' `
  -Headers $headers |Select-Object -Property EnvelopeDocuments -ExpandProperty EnvelopeDocuments | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name -SkipLast 1 |Out-File .\docName.txt
 
$IDList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$NameList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
  foreach($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines(".\DocID.txt"))
  {
 
 
$IDList.add($line)
 
#Write-Host Added $Line to ID List
 
 
  }
  #Write-Output $IDList
 
  foreach($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines(".\DocName.txt"))
  {
    $NoExt = $Line.Substring(0, $Line.Length - 4)
    $NameList.add($NoExt)
 
#Write-Host Added $NoExt to Name List
 
 
  }
  #Write-Output $NameList
 
 
$DN = $Namelist.Count
$outputFileExtension = ".PDF"
While($DN -ge 0)
{
$DocID = $IDList[$DN]
$DocName = $NameList[$DN]
 
 
#Write-Host $IDList[$DN]
#Write-Host $NameList[$DN]
 
    Invoke-RestMethod `
    -Uri "${apiUri}/v2.1/accounts/${accountId}/envelopes/${envelopeId}/documents/${DocID}" `
    -Method 'GET' `
    -Headers $headers `
    -UseDefaultCredentials `
    -OutFile C:\PowershellPdfs\${DocName}${outputFileExtension}
    #Real output 
 
    #test output
    #-OutFile O:/Data/Docusign/v
 
    $DN = $DN - 1
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
}
 
 
 
 
}
 
Write-Output "Done."
 
 
`
```

and the logs are:

```
PS>$global:?
True
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript end
End time: 20230322094117
**********************
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript start
Start time: 20230322094323
Username: HLB-PORTAL-002\_svc_ichan_hlb
RunAs User: HLB-PORTAL-002\_svc_ichan_hlb
Configuration Name: 
Machine: HLB-PORTAL-002 (Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.17763.0)
Host Application: powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\Users\_svc_ichan_hlb\Desktop\Docusign-Document-Pull-master\launcher.ps1
Process ID: 6300
PSVersion: 5.1.17763.3770
PSEdition: Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.1.17763.3770
BuildVersion: 10.0.17763.3770
CLRVersion: 4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion: 3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion: 2.3
SerializationVersion: 1.1.0.1
**********************
Transcript started, output file is .\logs\launcher.log
Welcome to the DocuSign PowerShell Launcher

Quickstart Enabled, please wait


Enters the pulldocs statement
0
0
Invoke-RestMethod : The user name or password is incorrect.
At C:\Users\_svc_ichan_hlb\Desktop\Docusign-Document-Pull-master\PullDocs.ps1:100 char:5
+     Invoke-RestMethod `
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-RestMethod], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

Invoke-RestMethod : The user name or password is incorrect.
At C:\Users\_svc_ichan_hlb\Desktop\Docusign-Document-Pull-master\PullDocs.ps1:100 char:5
+     Invoke-RestMethod `
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-RestMethod], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

0
0
Invoke-RestMethod : The user name or password is incorrect.
At C:\Users\_svc_ichan_hlb\Desktop\Docusign-Document-Pull-master\PullDocs.ps1:100 char:5
+     Invoke-RestMethod `
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-RestMethod], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

Invoke-RestMethod : The user name or password is incorrect.
At C:\Users\_svc_ichan_hlb\Desktop\Docusign-Document-Pull-master\PullDocs.ps1:100 char:5
+     Invoke-RestMethod `
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-RestMethod], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

0
0
Invoke-RestMethod : The user name or password is incorrect.
At C:\Users\_svc_ichan_hlb\Desktop\Docusign-Document-Pull-master\PullDocs.ps1:100 char:5
+     Invoke-RestMethod `
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-RestMethod], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

Invoke-RestMethod : The user name or password is incorrect.
At C:\Users\_svc_ichan_hlb\Desktop\Docusign-Document-Pull-master\PullDocs.ps1:100 char:5
+     Invoke-RestMethod `
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-RestMethod], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

0
0
Invoke-RestMethod : The user name or password is incorrect.
At C:\Users\_svc_ichan_hlb\Desktop\Docusign-Document-Pull-master\PullDocs.ps1:100 char:5
+     Invoke-RestMethod `
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-RestMethod], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

Invoke-RestMethod : The user name or password is incorrect.
At C:\Users\_svc_ichan_hlb\Desktop\Docusign-Document-Pull-master\PullDocs.ps1:100 char:5
+     Invoke-RestMethod `
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-RestMethod], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

0
0
Invoke-RestMethod : The user name or password is incorrect.
At C:\Users\_svc_ichan_hlb\Desktop\Docusign-Document-Pull-master\PullDocs.ps1:100 char:5
+     Invoke-RestMethod `
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-RestMethod], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

Invoke-RestMethod : The user name or password is incorrect.
At C:\Users\_svc_ichan_hlb\Desktop\Docusign-Document-Pull-master\PullDocs.ps1:100 char:5
+     Invoke-RestMethod `
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-RestMethod], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

0
0
Invoke-RestMethod : The user name or password is incorrect.
At C:\Users\_svc_ichan_hlb\Desktop\Docusign-Document-Pull-master\PullDocs.ps1:100 char:5
+     Invoke-RestMethod `
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-RestMethod], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

Invoke-RestMethod : The user name or password is incorrect.
At C:\Users\_svc_ichan_hlb\Desktop\Docusign-Document-Pull-master\PullDocs.ps1:100 char:5
+     Invoke-RestMethod `
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-RestMethod], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

Done.
```

We tried -usedefaultcredentials
and we cant find any other information

Here are the schedule task settings

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEhKD.png)

It calls a batch file that runs the powershell script

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1omhY.png)

Here is the batch file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xq6pc.png)

Here is the launch script that leads to the document pulling script

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop" # force stop on failure

$configFile = ".\settings.json"


if ((Test-Path $configFile) -eq $False) {
    Write-Output "Error: "
    Write-Output "First copy the file '.\config\settings.example.json' to '$configFile'."
    Write-Output "Next, fill in your API credentials, Signer name and email to continue."
}

Start-Transcript -Path .\logs\launcher.log -Append
# Check that we have an email address stored after running the 2 Admin code example
# in case the file was created before - delete it


# Get required environment variables from .\config\settings.json file
$config = Get-Content $configFile -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
function isCFR {
    $response = New-TemporaryFile
    $accessToken = Get-Content .\ds_access_token.txt
    $accountId = Get-Content .\API_ACCOUNT_ID

    Invoke-RestMethod `
        -Uri "https://api.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/$accountId/settings" `
        -Method 'GET' `
        -Headers @{
        'Authorization' = "Bearer $accessToken";
        'Content-Type'  = "application/json";
    } `
        -OutFile $response
    $env:CFR_STATUS = Select-String -Pattern '"require21CFRpt11Compliance":"true"' -Path $response
}


function  checkOrgId {

    if ($config.ORGANIZATION_ID -eq "{ORGANIZATION_ID}" ) {
        Write-Output "No Organization Id in the config file. Looking for one via the API"
        # Get required environment variables from .\config\settings.json file
        $accessToken = Get-Content .\ds_access_token.txt

        $base_path = "https://api.docusign.net/management"

        $response = New-TemporaryFile
        Invoke-RestMethod `
            -Uri "$base_path/v2/organizations" `
            -Method 'GET' `
            -Headers @{
            'Authorization' = "Bearer $accessToken";
            'Content-Type'  = "application/json";
        } `
            -OutFile $response

        $organizationId = $(Get-Content $response | ConvertFrom-Json).organizations[0].id

        $config.ORGANIZATION_ID = $organizationId
        write-output $config | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content $configFile
        Write-Output "Organization id has been written to config file..."
        Remove-Item $response

    }
}


function startLauncher {


        # Load via Quickstart
        if ($config.QUICKSTART -eq "true" ) {
            if ($null -eq $firstPassComplete) {
                Write-Output ''
                Write-Output "Quickstart Enabled, please wait"
                write-Output ''
                powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command .\code_grant.ps1 -clientId $($config.INTEGRATION_KEY_AUTH_CODE) -clientSecret $($config.SECRET_KEY) -apiVersion $("eSignature")


                if ((Test-Path "./ds_access_token.txt") -eq $true) {
                    Write-Output "Enters the pulldocs statement"
                    powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass  -Command .\PullDocs.ps1 -clientId $($config.INTEGRATION_KEY_AUTH_CODE) -clientSecret $($config.SECRET_KEY) -apiVersion $("eSignature")

                    # This is to prevent getting stuck on the
                    # first example after trying it the first time
                    $firstPassComplete = "true"

                    
                }
                else {
                    Write-Error "Failed to retrieve OAuth Access token, check your settings.json and that port 8080 is not in use"  -ErrorAction Stop
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function launchJWT {


        # Load via Quickstart
        if ($config.QUICKSTART -eq "true" ) {
            if ($null -eq $firstPassComplete) {
                Write-Output ''
                Write-Output "Quickstart Enabled, please wait"
                write-Output ''
                powershell.exe -Command .\jwt.ps1 -clientId $($config.INTEGRATION_KEY_JWT) -apiVersion $("eSignature")


                if ((Test-Path "./ds_access_token.txt") -eq $true) {
                    powershell.exe -Command .\PullDocs.ps1

                    # This is to prevent getting stuck on the
                    # first example after trying it the first time
                    $firstPassComplete = "true"

                    
                }
                else {
                    Write-Error "Failed to retrieve OAuth Access token, check your settings.json and that port 8080 is not in use"  -ErrorAction Stop
                }
            }
        }
    }

Write-Output "Welcome to the DocuSign PowerShell Launcher"
#launchJWT
startLauncher
```

[This is the folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rddG4.png)

Comment: Maybe the account you use is configured to use a proxy and authorized while the account used in the task scheduler is not authorized on the proxy and request you to provide credentials.
Also strange to load the access token from a file. the access token is expiring and should be renewed at regular interval. You should obtain a new access token while running the scheduled task.

Comment: @Hazrelle now on the proxy is that on our side or the api's side? We also have it redoing an access code every time in the launch script, the main script calls the one above, which has been causing us issues

Comment: You have to run the task as a user or a service account.  Default Task Schedule I s System Account which has no Environment so task fails.

Comment: @jdweng I updated my post, maybe that can provide more information

Comment: How can a task find "$accessToken = Get-Content .\ds_access_token.txt"?  You should have a variable indicating the start folder and add to location  $START_PATH = "c:\temp"  Then use "$accessToken = Get-Content ("#START_PATH" + "\ds_access_token.txt")

Comment: @jdweng i did that thanks! unfortunately im still getting the same error while using invoke-restmethod, where it says
Invoke-RestMethod : The user name or password is incorrect.
At C:\Users\_svc_ichan_hlb\Desktop\Docusign-Document-Pull-master\PullDocs.ps1:100 char:5
+     Invoke-RestMethod `

Comment: The code has to start from same folder where settings.json is located.  The credentials are in this file.  The data is put into the variable $config : $config = Get-Content $configFile -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json.  There error is due to the server refushing these credentials.  Read the beginning of the launch script which give instructions to create the json file.

Comment: Yes, thats correct and how i have it in the folder. it works 100% of the time when its not in a scheduled task. When it runs from a batch file or scheduled task it gives that error. outside of that it does not give that error. that is why i am confused to why its not working. Also the environment produces the same exact results no matter where its run.